# How to speedup this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Do you have some idea of how to speedup this query:

```
SELECT  Vosol = ( CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT Id
                                     FROM   trs.CollectionHeaderView AS chv
                                     WHERE  chv.ItemNum = itm.ItemNum
                                            AND chv.CollectionType = '1' )
                       THEN ISNULL(itm.Amount, 0)
                       ELSE 0
                  END ) ,
        Vakhast = ( CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT   Id
                                       FROM     trs.CollectionHeaderView AS chv
                                       WHERE    chv.ItemNum = itm.ItemNum
                                                AND chv.CollectionType = '2' )
                         THEN ISNULL(itm.Amount, 0)
                         ELSE 0
                    END )
FROM    trs.TrsDocRcvItem AS itm
        LEFT JOIN trs.TrsDocRcvHeader AS hdr ON itm.HeaderRef = hdr.Id
        LEFT JOIN acc.DL AS dl ON dl.Id = hdr.DLRef
        LEFT JOIN trs.TrsDocType AS docType ON docType.Id = hdr.DocTypeRef
        INNER JOIN sle.SleCustomer AS customer ON customer.DLRef = dl.Id
        LEFT JOIN trs.AccOperation AS operation ON operation.Id = itm.AccOperationRef
WHERE   hdr.DocTypeRef NOT IN ( 1141, 1142, 1241, 1242 )
        AND ( hdr.State = '1'
              OR hdr.State = '2'
            )
        AND operation.StateType = '1'
```

I'm trying to optimize sql query which now takes about 6 second to execute.
What more can I do to speedup this query? 
I'm using Microsoft Sql Server.

Comment: Do you have an execution plan so we can see the bottlenecks?

Comment: Why have you joined `acc.DL` and `sle.SleCustomer`. Is it really used for filtering records ?

Comment: yes, I used it.

Comment: this is my execution plan   http://sainaco.net/plan.sqlplan

Comment: Your query plan shows you need to create a covering index over TrsDocRcvItem.Try creating that missing index and executing post it. It is currently performing a scan operation with a high cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OUTER APPLY` to remove the two correlated sub-queries.

```
SELECT Vosol = CASE WHEN chv1 IS NOT NULL THEN Isnull(itm.Amount, 0) ELSE 0 END,
       Vakhast = CASE WHEN chv2 IS NOT NULL THEN Isnull(itm.Amount, 0) ELSE 0 END
FROM   trs.TrsDocRcvItem AS itm
       INNER JOIN trs.TrsDocRcvHeader AS hdr
              ON itm.HeaderRef = hdr.Id
       --LEFT JOIN acc.DL AS dl
       --       ON dl.Id = hdr.DLRef
       --LEFT JOIN trs.TrsDocType AS docType
             -- ON docType.Id = hdr.DocTypeRef
       --INNER JOIN sle.SleCustomer AS customer
       --        ON customer.DLRef = dl.Id
       INNER JOIN trs.AccOperation AS operation
              ON operation.Id = itm.AccOperationRef
       OUTER apply (SELECT Max(CASE WHEN chv.CollectionType = '1' THEN id END) AS chv1,
                           Max(CASE WHEN chv.CollectionType = '2' THEN id END) AS chv2
                    FROM   trs.CollectionHeaderView AS chv
                    WHERE  chv.ItemNum = itm.ItemNum
                           AND chv.CollectionType IN ( '1', '2' )) oa
WHERE  hdr.DocTypeRef NOT IN ( 1141, 1142, 1241, 1242 )
       AND hdr.State IN ( '1', '2' )
       AND operation.StateType = '1'
```

I have commented out the `acc.DL` and `sle.SleCustomer` tables. I don't see any use of it other than filtering records. If you really need it then uncomment it.

Also I have commented the `trs.TrsDocType` table which again has no use. Unless it has one to many relationship with `trs.TrsDocRcvHeader` table. If it has one to many relationship then the result simply get duplicated for no reason since you are not selecting anything from `trs.TrsDocType` table.

---

Still if the query is running slow then you need to create `Indexes` on the tables involved. Also make sure the `statistics` are up-to-date

---

After analyzing your execution plan, `TrsDocRcvItem` table costs `47%`. Creating a index on `TrsDocRcvItem` table should help the query

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NIX_TrsDocRcvItem
ON [Trs].[TrsDocRcvItem] (AccOperationRef,ItemNum,HeaderRef)
INCLUDE (Amount)
```

Suggested index from the execution plan you have posted

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [Trs].[TrsDocRcvItem] ([AccOperationRef])
INCLUDE ([ItemNum],[Amount],[HeaderRef])
```

Comment: thanks for your help.. my query result is 2636 row, but this query returs 3033 rows .

Comment: @ElhamAzadfar - Uncomment the joins

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  Vosol = ( CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT Id
                                     FROM   trs.CollectionHeaderView AS chv
                                     WHERE  chv.ItemNum = itm.ItemNum
                                            AND chv.CollectionType = '1' )
                       THEN ISNULL(itm.Amount, 0)
                       ELSE 0
                  END ) ,
        Vakhast = ( CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT   Id
                                       FROM     trs.CollectionHeaderView AS chv
                                       WHERE    chv.ItemNum = itm.ItemNum
                                                AND chv.CollectionType = '2' )
                         THEN ISNULL(itm.Amount, 0)
                         ELSE 0
                    END )
FROM    trs.TrsDocRcvItem AS itm
        INNER JOIN 
        (
    SELECT * FROM trs.TrsDocRcvHeader
    WHERE   DocTypeRef NOT IN ( 1141, 1142, 1241, 1242 )
                AND ( State = '1' OR State = '2' )

        ) hdr ON itm.HeaderRef = hdr.Id
        LEFT JOIN acc.DL AS dl ON dl.Id = hdr.DLRef
        LEFT JOIN trs.TrsDocType AS docType ON docType.Id = hdr.DocTypeRef
        INNER JOIN sle.SleCustomer AS customer ON customer.DLRef = dl.Id
        INNER JOIN 
        ( SELECT * FROM trs.AccOperation WHERE StateType = '1'
        ) operation operation.Id = itm.AccOperationRef
```

You can replace

```
WHERE   hdr.DocTypeRef NOT IN ( 1141, 1142, 1241, 1242 )
        AND ( hdr.State = '1'
              OR hdr.State = '2'
            )
        AND operation.StateType = '1'
```

To

```
INNER JOIN 
        (
    SELECT * FROM trs.TrsDocRcvHeader
    WHERE   DocTypeRef NOT IN ( 1141, 1142, 1241, 1242 )
                AND ( State = '1' OR State = '2' )

        ) hdr ON itm.HeaderRef = hdr.Id

INNER JOIN 
        ( SELECT * FROM trs.AccOperation WHERE StateType = '1'
        ) operation operation.Id = itm.AccOperationRef
```

I hope that it will help you.